# How can i fix gulp-sass installation error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm new to Gulp and want to install gulp-sass for my project. But it throws error. I tried to install another gulp packages like gulp-uglify, i don't have any trouble about them. It throws error for only gulp-sass. I reinstalled and updated node again but nothing changed. How can i fix this ? This is the error:

```
PS C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin> npm install gulp-sass
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\zenes\\Desktop\\enestekin\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.12.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: /path/to/executable/python2.7
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:193:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  /path/to/executable/python2.7 Error: not found: /path/to/executable/python2.7
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:193:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "/path/to/executable/python2.7". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "/path/to/executable/python2.7". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:193:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\zenes\\Desktop\\enestekin\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\zenes\Desktop\enestekin\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.12.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zenes\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-21T14_45_18_130Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you have Python installed?

Comment: @weirdan Yes, i have

Answer (score 1):

What is your node.js version?
I have seen this error when I use node 15.x version.
But after I reinstalled the 14.x version, I can install gulp-sass module successfully.
It is not good to use latest version of Node.js.
For the good experience, it is good to use LTS version(You must do it in production).
https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/